# Feel the need+of? is this correct? i dont think it is, but i may be wrong

Tags: grammar

"Why do you feel the need of convincing him to eat ice-cream?"

Comment: "Feel the need _to convince him_..." would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

It would not conventionally be used. The structure "feel the need *to* (infinitive)" is correct.

"Why do you feel the need to convince him to eat ice cream?" would be the correct way to phrase your question.